# After switching to SpringBoot from TomcatServerConf Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, thymeleaf

Initially, I started the project with IntelliJ Idea Tomcat Local Server configuration (everything worked), but decided to use Spring Boot Application. I added the main class, changed pom.xml (delete spring-context and add spring-boot-starter-parent, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter-tomcat, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-autoconfigure), after that application runs , GET-Method works, but POST - not supported. Help me please!!! Thank you!

Main.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {SpringConfig.class})
    public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Pom.xml to springBoot

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Main configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    /*
     *  Dispatcher configuration for serving static resources
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
        registry.addResourceHandler("assets/select2-develop/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

    /*
     *  Message externalization/internationalization
     */
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
        // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
        // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
        // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
        // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
        // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
        // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
        // for safer backwards compatibility.
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("over");
//      dataSource.setPassword("postgres");     Можно установить пароль для базы данных.
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

}
```

DispatcherSerlvet config

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherSerlvetIntitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }


    /* Класс знает теперь где находится spring конфигурация */

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    /* Все http запросы от пользователя посылаем на dispatcher servlet  */
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerCharacterEncodingFilter(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }

    private void registerCharacterEncodingFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = aContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

This is my exeption :

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/categories")
@Controller
public class CategoriesController {
    private CategoriesDao categoriesDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setCategoriesDAO(CategoriesDao categoriesDAO)
    {
        this.categoriesDAO = categoriesDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public  String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoriesDAO.index());
        return "categories/index";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") @Valid Category category,
                              BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("categories", categoriesDAO.index());
            return "categories/index";
        }
        categoriesDAO.addCategory(category);
        return "redirect:categories";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String deleteCategory(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        categoriesDAO.deleteCategory(id);
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String editCategory(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("editCategory", categoriesDAO.editCategory(id));
        return "categories/edit";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String updateCategory(@ModelAttribute("editCategory") Category updateCategory,
                                 @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        categoriesDAO.updateCategory(id, updateCategory);
        return "redirect:{id}/edit";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running your new Spring Boot setup? Normally you run local Spring Boot applications by executing the main class. Make sure that there isn't an instance of your application running in Tomcat as well.

Comment: Your dependencies are too many and remove `scanBasePackageClasses` from the `@SpringBootApplication` and implement the `configure` method for the `SpringBootServletInitializer` if you want to run it as a war file.

Comment: What do your controllers look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the configure method in the main class you could do:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
      SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Main.class);
    }
}
```

I think these dependencies should be enough (assuming you are using Thymeleaf):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT: Your ModelAttribute 'Category' might not be parsed successfully. Either the mapping fails, or maybe the validation? You might find out by adding an error handler and/or debugging the sessions.

Other ideas: Use @RestController instead of @Controller. Try to make the request mappings more explicit. Instead of on the class, put one on each method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/categories", produces = "application/json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  String index(Model model) {
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/categories", produces = "application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") @Valid Category category,
                          BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I remove some dependencies and implement the configure method in the main class, but it does't work. I also edit my question and add description of controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I found answer on my question. It was some problems with HiddenHttpMethodFilter. I just added this code in my Spring Config and extra dependencies was . It stared to work!!!

```
public FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter> filterRegistrationBean =
                new FilterRegistrationBean<HiddenHttpMethodFilter>(new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/*"));
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```